# Custom View in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to create a UITableView Section that contains two buttons aligned horizontally.  This would be similar to the Contacts app, where on the bottom of a specific contact page they have buttons lined up to Text the contact and share the contact.  However in my tableView, I want the two buttons to be placed in between other sections - so i can't set the table's header or footer view?  How would i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correct, you want something like this

**section 1**
your buttons
**section 2**

For this you can create custom headers/footers for sections instead of table. The methods you might be looking for are in UITableViewDelegate

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into subclassing UITableviewCell class, you can draw your custom view in there and use it, look at the UICatalog sample project in Apple site they do that there a lot